# How can I define period for weekly data in SPSS?

Tags: time-series, spss

I have weekly data. I would like to perform time series analysis on it. Refer to [Robjhyndman](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-weekly-data/), period of weekly data can be calculated by approximation 365.25/7 = 52.

How can I define period in SPSS for weekly data? The following is data examples which has `dd/mm/yyyy` format:

```
date,count
04/16/2013,17
04/23/2013,13
04/30/2013,13
.
.
.

09/27/2016,20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
COMPUTE count=XDATE.WEEK(date).
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!